# Left outer join fetch doesn't fill map collection properly (HQL)

Tags: hibernate, join, dictionary, one-to-many

I've got classes with mappings like this:

```
@Entity
public class CurrencyTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Timestamp version;

    @Column(length=32, unique=true)
    private String refCode;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="currencyTable", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  {CascadeType.ALL})
   @MapKey(name="currency")
   private Map<String, CurrencyTableRate> rateMap = new HashMap<String, CurrencyTableRate>();
}

@Entity
public class CurrencyTableRate{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Timestamp version;

    @Column(length=3)
    private String currency;

    @Basic
    private BigDecimal rateValue;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private CurrencyTable currencyTable;
}
```

There is one row in CurrencyTable and three rows in CurrencyTableRate referring to the CurrencyTable in database.

When I load CurrencyTable using HQL:

```
from CurrencyTable where refCode = :refCode
```

I get an entity with three entries in rateMap, but if I try this:

```
from CurrencyTable table left outer join fetch table.rateMap where refCode = :refCode
```

there is only one entry in rateMap.

I looked on query generated by Hibernate and ran it manually - it returned three rows, as expected, so it seems to be a problem with mapping them after fetching. Has anyone encuntered such a problem?
I use Hibernate version 3.2.6.ga and Oracle 10g

Comment: I have same problem and could not find solution. my query some time does not work and threw lazyInitializationException

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to add an alias to refCode. I don't think it will have an impact on the result, but just in case.

```
from CurrencyTable table left outer join fetch table.rateMap where table.refCode = :refCode
```

Second, turn on your SQL code and analyse what' really going on at SQL level. I had similar issues with HQL in such cases

```
from CurrencyTable table left outer join fetch table.rateMap map where map.id = :id
```

which I have to rewrite to

```
from CurrencyTable table left outer join fetch table.rateMap map where EXISTS (SELECT a.id from CurrencyTable table a INNER JOIN a.rateMap m WHERE m.id = :id and table.id=a.id)
```

Hope my hints will help.

Comment: I added aliases and it didn't have impact. As I wrote in question I looked on SQL query generated by Hibernate and ran it manually - it returned three rows, as expected. I used a workaround with running first query (without left outer join fetch) and then calling Hibernate.initialize on the map. As it's in my work I have no time to debug Hibernate to find out what's going on but such behaviour upsets me :-)